# Не идет дальше следующей страницы в веб браузере, Приложение на Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

Помогите разобраться и исправить. Приложение в Asp.Net должно работать как менеджер файлов. Но дальше одной ссылки не идет, возвращает на стартовую. Вот кусок кода, думаю здесь проблема:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceForSubDirectories.Controls.Clear();
    amount10To50 = 0; amountLess10 = 0; amountMore50 = 0;
    if (directory == null)
    {
        directory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    }
    ShowCurrendDirectory();  
    Count(directory);       
    ShowLenghtOfAllFiles();
}

protected void Link_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as LinkButton).Text == "..." + "<br/>")
    {
        directory = directory.Parent;
    }
    else
    {
        PlaceForSubDirectories.Controls.Clear();
        string subDirectory = Regex.Replace((sender as LinkButton).Text, "<br/>", "");
        directory = new DirectoryInfo(directory.FullName + @"\" + subDirectory);
    }
    Page_Load(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: 1. У Вас **Техт** в `LinkButton` "...<br/>"? 2. Текущий директорий на каком компьютере (и для какого процесса) вернет `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? 3. Не вызывайте `Page_Load`, этот метод предназначен для вызова кодом ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не факт, что проблема только в этом, но.
Экземпляр наследника Page создается на каждый запрос, то есть, Ваша проверка в Page_Load смысла в данной ситуации лишена: directory == null всегда будет true. Если сделать поле статическим, то оно будет одинаковым для всех пользователей приложения.
Чтобы значение директории сохранялось между запросами, Вам необходимо создать, как вариант, хотя, мягко говоря, не самый лучший, свойство DirectoryPath с путем к каталогу, которое будет сохранять значение во ViewState:

```
private DirectoryInfo _directory;

protected DirectoryPath
{
   get { return ViewState["DirectoryPath"].ToString(); }
   set { ViewState["DirectoryPath"] = value; _directory = null; }
}

protected DirectoryInfo Directory
{
   get
   {
      return (_directory ?? (_directory = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryPath));
   }
   set 
   { 
      DirectoryPath = value.FullName;
      _directory = value;
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some code...
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       DirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
    ListDirectory();
}

protected void Link_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender as LinkButton -- тоже не очень хорошо
    // <br/> в тексте кнопки -- тем более
    string text = (sender as LinkButton).Text;

    if (text.Equals("..."))
    {
        Directory = directory.Parent;
    }
    else
    {
        PlaceForSubDirectories.Controls.Clear();
        DirectoryPath = Path.Combine(DirectoryPath, text);
    }

    ListDirectory();
}       

private void ListDirectory()
{
    ShowCurrendDirectory();  
    Count(directory);       
    ShowLenghtOfAllFiles();
}
```

По идее так следует реализовывать все свойства, состояние которых должно сохраняться между запросами.

Метод Page_Load из обработчика события вызывать не стоит, как уже говорилось выше, если надо поменять стейт контролов, то надо завести для этого отдельный метод (показано выше).

Плюс ко всему хотелось бы сказать, что светить каталог bin пользователю идея плохая, хотя возможно это необходимо Вам в рамках задачи.

Comment: Поправил вам реализацию свойств так, чтобы их связь не "порвалась" неудачным присвоением значения. PS вы забыли `return` в коде `DirectoryPath.get`, будьте внимательнее

Comment: Спасибо огромное, не досмотрел.

Answer (score -4):

Нашел выход методом "тыка" : переменную directory в класе сделал статической.

Comment: А теперь проверьте как оно будет работать для нескольких пользователей :)

Comment: Не стоит искать ответ методом тыка, изучите матчасть.

Comment: @Mihanik71 пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее. Это было не дополнение вопроса, это был авторский ответ на свой вопрос. Да, он неправильный - но он остается ответом, а не дополнением.

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. автор сейчас ещё к одному неправильному ответу придёт, опубликует его и его тоже надо будет оставить?

Comment: @Mihanik71 удалять неправильные ответы нужно. Но не с такой формулировкой.